# Strange compiler error when using decltype in visual studio 2013

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-2013, decltype

```
template <typename Iter>
class CircularIterator
{
public:
    CircularIterator(Iter it, Iter end) : _curr(it), _begin(it), _end(end)
    {
        if (it == end)
        {
            throw std::runtime_error("Cannot create CircularIterator for empty range.");
        }
    }

    CircularIterator(const CircularIterator& other) :
        _curr(other._curr),
        _begin(other._begin),
        _end(other._end)
    {
        // Do nothing.
    }

    CircularIterator& operator=(const CircularIterator& other)
    {
        CircularIterator copy(other);

        Swap(copy);

        return *this;
    }

    template <typename Y>
    void Swap(CircularIterator<Y>& other)
    {
        using std::swap;

        swap(_curr, other._curr);
        swap(_begin, other._begin);
        swap(_end, other._end);
    }

    auto operator*() -> decltype(((Iter*)nullptr)->operator*())
    {
        return *_curr;
    }

    auto operator->() -> decltype(_curr.operator->())
    {
        return _curr.operator->();
    }

    void Next()
    {
        ++_curr;
        if (_curr == _end)
        {
            _curr = _begin;
        }
    }

private:
    Iter _curr;
    Iter _begin;
    Iter _end;
};

template <typename T>
auto CreateCircularIterator(T& container) -> CircularIterator<decltype(begin(container))>
{
    return CircularIterator<decltype(begin(container))>(begin(container), end(container));
}

void foo()
{
    const size_t numBuffers = 2;
    vector<vector<char>> buffers(numBuffers);

    auto bufferIter = CreateCircularIterator(buffers);
    void* buffPtr = bufferIter->data(); // Error here
}
```

I'm getting the error `error C2839: invalid return type 'int' for overloaded 'operator ->'` on that last line, but it goes away if I change the signature of the operator-> overload to `auto operator->() -> decltype(((Iter*)nullptr)->operator->())`

Is this a compiler bug? Or am I misunderstanding how to use decltype?

Comment: Can we have an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) please? A monolithic chunk of code, including header includes and such, that someone can copy-paste as is and try to reproduce the problem?

Comment: Move member declare to the head of the class, at least before _curr is used in decltype